# Check if PDO executed query has results to fetch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an object to run all my database queries and in that object I have a method called `runQuery()` that is called for any type of query.

This is just an illustration code:

```
public function runQuery($query){
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

My problem is that when I run `$stmt->errorCode();` to see if everything went fine I receive the error code: HY000

After some search I discovered that this error is triggered everytime I do a `fetchAll()` on queries that have nothing to fetch like `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

My question is, how can I verify if the executed query has content to fetch or not without exploding the query to see if the first word is not one of those three?

Comment: Usually it's `$stmt = $db->prepare()` and then `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just returning **wrong value** from this function.

It often happens that learners **overcomplicate** their code, just because they know no right way, which is really simple and powerful. And then they make it even more complicated, asking a question how to resolve the problem that was caused by the *initially wrong* overcomplicated approach. But all can be resolved in a really simple way:

You have to return the **statement**, not rows. It will make our function extremely handy and way more useful yet it will be kept as simple as this "illustration code". And it will solve your problem as just a side effect.

```
public function runQuery($query, $data = array()){
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}
```

## is **all** the code you need

Want to get all the rows at once? Just call your function this way

```
$obj->runQuery($sql)->fetchAll();
```

As you can see, in such a case fetch method can be simply "linked" to the `runQuery()` method call, thanks to the very neat OOP syntax feature called "method chaining". All you need is to return the statement, not result.

Not much writing, but enormous flexibility. Now you can get *any* result type you want.

In fact, you're limiting yourself to just one result set type, making it complicated to get another type. But PDO already has billions of result set types - you need only to use them.

Say, you need just a user name. What would you do with you function? Hassle with nested arrays? What about this

```
$name = $obj->runQuery("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?",[$id])->fetchColumn();
```

Look, PDO already have a handy method for you. What about single row?

```
$user = $obj->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?",[$email])->fetch();
```

Or, if you want to get a column, but not as a nested but simple one-dimensional array? Again PDO has a method for you:

```
$ids = $obj->runQuery("SELECT id FROM news WHERE date=?",[$date])->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

And there are other wonderful modes, which I described in my article, [The only proper guide on PDO](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall). Gonna dump them all? Really?

Or, take your initial problem with DML query. What if you want to get the number of affected rows? *voila* -

```
$inserted = $obj->runQuery($insertQuery,$insertData)->rowCount();
```

Look - all you need is to return the statement and then use method chaining to get the result in the desired form.

As a bonus, you don't even need to rewrite your existing code that was using inner `fetchAll()` call. If you were looping over returned result using `foreach` - you still can use the same code, using returned statement all the same:

```
$data = $obj->runQuery($sql);
foreach($data as $row) ...
```

-- just try it, it works!